# Jquery Datatables Pagination Not Updating

Tags: jquery, datatables, server-side

I'm returning this json to my datatable and it adds the data to the table but the entries are 0 to 0 out of 0. I'm not sure if it's an error on my part or a bug with their plugin but based on their documentation it looks right.

https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Pic of the table
http://tinypic.com/r/2vdqjxz/8

Javascript

```
 $('#query-results-table').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": webroot + "AdminQueryBuilder/PreviewQueryResultProcessing?QueryID=" + queryID
    });
```

C# Model

```
public class ReturnedDataTableParameter
    {
        public int draw { get; set; }

        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

        public List<List<string>> data { get; set; }

    }
```

JSON:

```
{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 200,
"recordsFiltered": 200,
"data": [
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
],
[
"1",
"Y",
"RS14:35"
]
]
}
```

Comment: show me entire source

Comment: @lv0gun9 Added some more code

Comment: is the requested data being returned when you inspect the actual request in network tab of browser console?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes It is the json I posted above is the response. It puts the data in the table. It just doesn't update the pagination

Comment: I checked your json and it was not problem. and forget your data model. it couldn't cause of this error. 
browser or other things may it cause imo.

Comment: Are you using v1.9 or 1.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured the problem out. The Datatable was being re-declared later down the page on the same element which was resulting in this weird issue.